# How to display and add tasks to file according to priorities using Java

Tags: java, file

I need to display/list the contents of a txt file in the ascending order of priority. So, should I need to take a seperate input for priority of task or can I splice the input line?

```
private static void show() {
    
    String[] items = getData("task.txt");
    
    if (items.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("There are no pending tasks!");
    } else {
        for (int i = items.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {    
                System.out.printf("[%d] %s\n", i + 1, items[i]);
            
        }
    }
```

My getData looks like this:

```
private static String[] getData(String file) {
    ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner s=null;
    
    try {
         s = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        while (s.hasNextLine()){
            dataList.add(s.nextLine());
        }s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem to open \"task.txt\".");
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    String[] items = new String[dataList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i] = dataList.get(i);
    }

    return items;
}
```

> Input: 
> 10 the thing i need to do 
> 5 water the plants 
> 11 clean house

> Output:
>  5 water the plants 
> 10 the thing i need to do 
> 11 clean house

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort the ArrayList datalist:
(I am assuming that the "priority item" format is already in it)

```
dataList.sort((o1, o2) -> {
        Integer priority1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.split(" ")[0]);
        Integer priority2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.split(" ")[0]);
        return priority1.compareTo(priority2);
    });
```

Put this right after the try-catch-finally-block.

Comment: I have considered String[] items which inputs priority in the same line, so priority is the last element from String array that should be compared with the next input and sort

Comment: If its the last element you just need to change [0] to [1] (ofc when there are only 2 entries)

Comment: How can it be solved if there are >2 entries?

Comment: you just need to get the last entry of the array. like array[array.length-1]